# "Function of functions" multiline alignment

Tags: alignment

I'm struggling to create an alignment such as the one in the pic:[image]
How to do something like this? Is it possible only with the align environment?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do something similar with `align`, though I might suggest an `aligned` environment which will make the spacing somewhat more compact.

```
\[\begin{aligned}
T^{t}:V^{*} &\rightarrow U^{*} \\
f      &\mapsto T^{t}(f) : & U &\rightarrow \mathbb{K}\\
       &                 & u &\mapsto T^{t}(f)(u) = (f \circ T)(u).
\end{aligned}\]
```

[image: aligned example]

Though the spacing of your original image almost suggests to me that it was done with something like an array environment:

```
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\[\begin{array}{ccccccccl}
T^{t}&:&V^{*} &\rightarrow &U^{*} \\
& & f       &\mapsto &T^{t}(f) &: &U &\rightarrow &\mathbb{K}\\
& &         &        &         &  & u &\mapsto &T^{t}(f)(u) = (f \circ T)(u).
\end{array}\]
```

[image: array example]

I'm honestly not sure which I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{5}
T^{t}: \quad & V^{*} & \quad \rightarrow \quad & U^{*}            &   &                   &       &                               \\
             & f     & \quad \mapsto \quad     & T^{t}(f) : \quad & U & \quad \rightarrow & \quad & \mathbb{K}                    \\
             &       & \quad                   &                  & u & \quad \mapsto     & \quad & T^{t}(f)(u) = (f \circ T)(u).
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]